# How To Display Markdown Text In Command Line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a command line tool that needs to display short help files on hot key inputs.

Currently help files are in markdown format.

Is there an easy way to display that markdown text in command line formatted?

Comment: Formatted how? There isn't *that* much you can do to format text on the command line, e.g. different font sizes aren't really possible.

Comment: define "easy". what may be such for one may not be for another... have you done a google search? there are lots of options - one is installing a viewer like this one: https://github.com/axiros/terminal_markdown_viewer

Comment: I'm looking for some package that will take MD file format, convert it to something that will display close to that format in command line (as much as command line can accommodate the formatting).  Anything like that exists?

Comment: yes something like that exists, but you have to search to see what is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nd) tool can do it. It is written in node.js and primarily aimed at node.js package documentation. Which may or may not be suitable for your needs.

Comment: In the vein of non-`python3` modules, https://github.com/charmbracelet/glow might be a superior choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rich module as well.

```py
from rich.console import Console
from rich.markdown import Markdown
console = Console()
with open('path/to/your/markdown.md') as f:
    md = Markdown(f.read())
    console.print(md)
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical recommendation I've found is `mdless`, which is written in Ruby and needs to be installed using `gem install mdless` (more information at [Github](https://github.com/ttscoff/mdless)).

A simpler (single binary) implementation however is `mdcat`, which is written in Rust and can be found at [Github](https://github.com/swsnr/mdcat). It also includes precompiled binaries ready for download.

Why use such tools instead of just `cat` when *"Markdown is already human readable"*? **Colors and simple emphasis!** (just imagine this answer would be rendered without highlights of the cli-commands, it's a lot harder to find the relevant information quickly)